# Ceiling function apparently rounds incorrectly

Tags: r, rounding, ceil

Could someone please explain why R has a problem with rounding/ceiling and how you can make sure that it calculates correctly?

```
N = 50e3
x = vector(length = N)
p = 0.995

ceiling(length(x)*(1-p))
251

ceiling(N*(1-p))
251

ceiling(N*0.005)
250

ceiling(50e3*0.005)
250
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal

Comment: I didn't think this was an exact duplicate because of the "and how can you make sure that it calculates correctly?" part ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@rawr links to [Why are these numbers not equal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal) , which explains the fundamental issues with floating-point computation. In this case:

```r
print((1-0.995) - 0.005)
## [1] 4.336809e-18
```

Because of this, `(1-0.005)*5e4` is *slightly* greater than 250 (to see this you have to `print((1-0.005)*5e4, digits=22)`, because R *prints* a rounded representation by default) so `ceiling()` pushes the answer up to 251.

In this *particular* case it looks like you can get the desired answer by rounding `(1-p)` to three decimal places, `ceiling(N*round(1-p,3))`  — but you should definitely read the linked answer and think about whether this solution will be robust for all of your needs.